# Using React.js in WordPress

Tags: javascript

I want to add a "Widget" that is built with React.js to my WordPress site. It will not be dependent on any outside data. Besides adding npm modules and adding build processes to my Gruntfile (to convert JSX to JS), what other steps do I need to take to show a very simple React Component like below?

```
var React = require('react');   
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            name: "Jake"
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h1> {this.state.name} </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
} );    
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById( 'app' ) );
```

Where would this JavaScript file live in the typical WordPress file structure?

Comment: Are you building a plugin or a theme?